# Как сделать поверку на наличие индекса в списке?

Tags: python, list

У меня есть список `nickname`. Он состоит из двух слов. Я должен сделать так, что если пользователь пишет "ник Винокур", то сам ник кидается в переменную `nick`, а если он после слова "ник" ничего не написал, ему программа кое-что пишет. Дело в том, что я беру данные от пользователя и делаю такой код:
`nickname = text.split()`. Далее я пишу: `nick = nickname[1]`. Всё готово, **но как сделать, чтобы проверялся список на наличие индекса [1]?** Если его не будет в списке, выведется кое-что.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if len(nickname) < 2:
    print('кое-что')
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверить на индекс в списке можно, например, так:

```
def index_check(index):
    nickname = ['nickname1', 'nickname2']
    try:
       return nickname[int(index)]
    except IndexError as e:
       return e
```

Проверить наличие конкретного никнейма в списке:

```
def name_check(name):
    nickname = ['nickname1', 'nickname2']
    return name in nickname
```